# C# RegEx Pattern to Split a String into 2 Character Substring

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to figure out a regex to use to split a string into 2 character substring.

Let's say we have the following string:

```
string str = "Idno1";
string pattern = @"\w{2}";
```

Using the pattern above will get me "Id" and "no", but it will skip the "1" since it doesn't match the pattern. I would like the following results:

```
string str = "Idno1"; // ==> "Id" "no" "1 "
string str2 = "Id n o 2"; // ==> "Id", " n", " o", " 2"
```

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this. I would simply iterate over the characters and copy them into an array. A regex can match two-character groups, but how will you match the remaining character?

Comment: `@"\w{1,2}"` will give you what you are looking for. http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cw%7b1%2c2%7d&i=Id+n+o+2

Answer (score 3):

Linq can make easy the code. [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T89O42) version works

The idea: I have a `chunkSize` = 2 as your requirement, then, `Take` the string at the index (2,4,6,8,...) to get the chunk of chars and `Join` them to `string`.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ProperFormat(string s)
    {
        var chunkSize = 2;
        return s.Where((x,i) => i % chunkSize == 0)
               .Select((x,i) => s.Skip(i * chunkSize).Take(chunkSize))
               .Select(x=> string.Join("", x));
    }
```

With the input, I have the output

```
Idno1 --> 
Id
no
1

Id n o 2 -->
Id
 n
 o
 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq is really better in this case. You can use this method - it will allow to split string in chunks of arbitrary size:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitInChunks(string s, int size = 2)
{
    return s.Select((c, i) => new {c, id = i / size})
        .GroupBy(x => x.id, x => x.c)
        .Select(g => new string(g.ToArray()));
}
```

But if you are bound to regex, use this code:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitInChunksWithRegex(string s, int size = 2)
{
    var regex = new Regex($".{{1,{size}}}");
    return regex.Matches(s).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
}
```